# Apple unified logging - how to get file name and line number

Tags: ios, macos, logging

Apple's [`Unified Logging` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) states:

> Don’t include symbolication information or source file line numbers in messages. The system automatically captures this information.

But in Console I don't see a filename, class name, function name, or line numbers.

How can I have those in my logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os_log` doesn't currently give line numbers/function names for Swift code in Console.app, or through the `log stream` command.

If you really need it - you can use [Literal Expressions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_literal-expression) to pass the information manually via `NSLog` or `os_log` like this:

`os_log(.info, "Log message from file: %s, line: %i, column: %i", #file, #line, #column)`

It may be tempting to wrap `os_log` to always include this information, but Apple suggests not doing so for performance reasons.

Comment: Not sure how this is "the best answer" it doesn't answer the actual question. This tells you how to have the Swift compiler automatically generate information for you.  The question is asking about how to view information in the `Console` application

Comment: @kdubb thanks for pointing that. I updated the answer, so now it should be more precise

Answer (score 7):

Indeed, even macOS Catalina beta (build 19A501i) does not show source lines in *Console.app*.

However, the `log` command line tool does show source information for simulated devices (macOS 10.14 onwards).

The following command will show log information for all simulated devices currently booted (running) in the simulator. If no simulated devices are currently running the command will fail.

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level debug --color always --source`

You can filter out everything which does not come from your program by using a subsystem in `os_log` calls, and applying a predicate to the streamed logged data. For example, if your subsystem is `com.subsystem.my`, you can use

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level debug --color always --predicate '(subsystem BEGINSWITH "com.subsystem.my")' --source`

The source code information will be shown after the TTL column.

You can also filter by process (i.e. the name of your target), in case you didn't set up a subsystem

`xcrun simctl spawn booted log stream --level debug --color always --predicate '(process == "MyProcess")' --source`

However, this will normally result in too many log messages since information logged by other frameworks will also be included.

Also, instead of `booted`, you can use the name of the actual simulated device (to stream log data from that device alone).

Answer (score 1):

Till apple fixes this issue,
I've created a simple extension

```swift
import os

extension Logger {
  init(subsystem: String = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, context: String) {
    let category = "\(file):\(line):\(function), \(context)"
    self.init(subsystem: subsystem, category: category )
  }
}
```

Usages:

```swift
Logger(context: "LoginFLow").debug("Hello World")
```

We can even remove param name to make it more cleaner:

```swift
import os

extension Logger {
  init(subsystem: String = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "", file: String = #file, function: String = #function, line: Int = #line, _ context: String) {
    let category = "\(file):\(line):\(function), \(context)"
    self.init(subsystem: subsystem, category: category )
  }
}
```

Usages:

```swift
Logger("LoginFLow").debug("Hello World")
```

Note: If you wish to use the original Logger, just remove the context param and it will use its original init provided by apple.

```swift
Logger().debug("Hello World")
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. Is there a way to declare the logger once per struct/class and than only use the class variable?

Comment: Logger().debug("Hello World")

Here we are creating the instance, if you wish to keep a local property inside your class, you can easily do so by declaring a let property.

something like this: 

let logger = Logger()

And use it as logger.debug("Hello World")

Hope this helps

Comment: But in that case we use the default `Logger` implementation again and not your custom one. Also if I declare your Logger extension like you described the `function` property doesn't work any longer as it only shows the class/struct name all the time. Sorry, if I was a bit unclear with my initial question.