# os_signposter Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type > 'StaticString'

Tags: swift, operating-system

We went with the same issue in os_log [Using os_log to log function arguments, or other dynamic data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53025698/using-os-log-to-log-function-arguments-or-other-dynamic-data)
so here we go again:

```
let intervalId = "GetCategoriesUseCase"
let state = signposter.beginInterval(intervalId, id: signpostID)
signposter.endInterval(intervalId, state)
```

yields

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type
> 'StaticString'

how I am supposed to provide two matching names short of copypasting the string???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StaticString` conforms to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral` so you can change the declaration to

```
let intervalId: StaticString = "GetCategoriesUseCase"
```